# Creating a Combo Login/Signup Form with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a combo-menu with login and signup functionality using Bootstrap. I have followed Bootstrap and W3Schools samples and everything seems alright, but only the login form is displayed, while the signup form does not display when the Signup tab is clicked.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tabList">
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="login.php" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="true"><?= Translate::get("Login") ?></a>    
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="signup-tab" data-toggle="tab"  href="login.php" role="tab" aria-controls="signup"><?= Translate::get("Sign Up")?></a>
  </li>

</ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab">
          <form class="form">
              <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="<?= Translate::get("Email") ?>"/>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="<?= Translate::get("Password") ?>" />
              <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="<?= Translate::get("Log In")?>"/>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="signup-tab">
          <input type="email" placeholder="<?= Translate::get("Email")?>"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="<?= Translate::get("Password") ?>"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="<?= Translate::get("Enter Password Again") ?>" />
          <input type="submit" value="<?= Translate::get("Sign Up")?>"/>
      </div> 
</div>
        
<script src="js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And the output is like this (The Signup tab does not work):

[image: tab]

Comment: Remove login.php and signup.php from `<a>` . You are supposed to hit that files on form submit. And place script tag below body tag

Answer (score 0):

It is critical that the id of the div used in the tab content be given as href of login or signup hyperlinks. So, for the login button, we will have `href="#login"` and for the signup button, we'll have `href="#signup"`.  Solved ✓